# Magento doesn't send any mail order

Tags: php, email, magento

When a customer makes an order, I don't receive the email of the order itself. It seems that Magento doesn't send the email because they aren't processed by the mail server (they don't arrive at all). I tried different SMTP extensions, the most "famous" seems "SMTP Schroeder", but any of them works at all. The mail server is Mandrill.

The Magento version in use is 1.7.0.2. If I send the email order in the backend from "sellings ---> orders ---> [customer] ---> send email again", it appears this string in the error.log of my server:

[Thu Nov 05 17:38:25 2015] [error] [client 37.59.14.152] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/vhosts/www.venditascacchi.it/httpdocs/app/etc/local.xml

Anyone can help me? I'm stuck with this problem since ages. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

> [Thu Nov 05 17:38:25 2015] [error] [client 37.59.14.152] client
>   denied by server configuration:
>   /var/www/vhosts/www.venditascacchi.it/httpdocs/app/etc/local.xml

I wouldn't worry about that -- it's common and I've got sites with that error message sending emails just fine.

Here's what I would do to solve the issue:

1. Check that your mail delivery is not disabled.  You can find this in System->Configuration->System (near the bottom)->Mail Options.  Make sure "Disabled Mail Settings" is not disabled.
2. If that is set correctly, then I'd create a script to test that mail outside of Magento is being delivered:

   $to      = 'nobody@example.com';
   $subject = 'the subject';
   $message = 'hello';
   $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
       'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
       'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

   mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

If that doesn't work, then I'd check with your host to see why your mail server isn't processing mail.

Also -- for those on a later version of Magento -- mail is sent on cron in some versions, so make sure your cron is running.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, where should I try that script?

Comment: You can just add it to the root directory and call it like testmail.php.   then go to www.yourdomain.com/testmail.php

Comment: You updated the $to to be your email address right?  If so -- you just ruled it out as being a Magento issue.  It's an issue with your server not sending emails.   Do you use a 3rd party service for email or rely on the local machine?

Comment: Sure, I put my personal email but it didn't work.
I use Mandrill for sending email with the SMTP Schroeder extension. I even tried other extensions but still no working. 

Can it be an issue related to the Magento version (1.7.0.2)? I use the same extension with other website and they all work correctly, the only difference is the Magento version itself.